# Use mean in ggplot boxplots instead of median

Tags: r, ggplot2, mean, median

Is it possible to use the mean in a ggplot boxplot instead of the median?
Reason I ask is that in my data the median = 0.0 and mean = 0.40 and I am interested in the mean.

Comment: already answered see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19876505/boxplot-show-the-value-of-mean

Comment: [Related question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25999677/how-to-plot-mean-and-standard-error-in-boxplot-in-r) for how to use your own statistics in the place of standard boxplot statistics in ggplot2.

Answer (score 6):

From the help `?geom_boxplot`:

```
library(ggplot2)
# It's possible to draw a boxplot with your own computations if you
# use stat = "identity":
y <- rnorm(100)
df <- data.frame(
  x = 1,
  y0 = min(y),
  y25 = quantile(y, 0.25),
  y50 = median(y),   # <=== replace by mean
  y75 = quantile(y, 0.75),
  y100 = max(y)
)
ggplot(df, aes(x)) +
  geom_boxplot(
    aes(ymin = y0, lower = y25, middle = y50, upper = y75, ymax = y100),
    stat = "identity"
  )
```

So you could pre-compute the box values, use `stat="identity"` and replace `median` by `mean`.